# MongoDB group by with sort and limit for each group

Tags: mongodb

For instance I have a collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "abc", "score" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "abc", "score" : 15 }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "abc", "score" : 20 }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "xyz", "score" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "xyz", "score" : 15 }
{ "_id" : 6, "name" : "xyz", "score" : 20 }
```

How can I do a query in Mongodb to group by `name` then sort by `score` and take it with `limit=2`. I want to get like this:

```
    {"_id": "abc", "items": [
          { "_id" : 3, "name" : "abc", "score" : 20 },
          { "_id" : 2, "name" : "abc", "score" : 15 }]
    }
    {"_id": "xyz", "items": [
          { "_id" : 6, "name" : "xyz", "score" : 20 },
          { "_id" : 5, "name" : "xyz", "score" : 15 }]
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My solution is

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$sort:{name:-1, score:-1}},
    {$group:{_id:"$name",items:{$push:{score:"$score"}}}}, 
    {$project:{items:{$slice:["$items", 2]}}}])
.pretty()
```

returns

```
{
    "_id" : "abc",
    "items" : [
        {
            "score" : 20
        },
        {
            "score" : 15
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "xyz",
    "items" : [
        {
            "score" : 20
        },
        {
            "score" : 15
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Mongodb does not guarantee that previous sorts are preserved by a group stage, on a bigger dataset or on sharded clusters it would mess up the order.
Afaik there is no way to do this

Comment: I am exactly stuck in this phase now, my group by is returning random result set every time